# Destroy an object in a Volt store collection

Tags: voltrb

I'm trying to delete an object in a store collection using:

```
store.widgets.where(code: 'xyz').first.destroy
```

and get the following result from the promise:

```
[:@action, :@realized, :@exception, :@value, :@error, :@delayed, :@prev, :@next]
```

and the object is not deleted/destroyed.

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by my own (legacy) #destroy method in Object overriding the behaviour of the promise chain from `first` to `destroy`.

Can confirm that both

```
store.widgets.delete(store.widgets.where(code: 'xyz').first)
```

and

```
store.widgets.where(code: 'xyz').first.destroy
```

do work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
store.widgets.delete(store.widgets.where(code: 'xyz').first)
```

Or if you really want to just delete the first item:

```
store.widgets.delete_at(0)
```